# Can't resolve 'chart.js/auto'

Tags: reactjs, frontend, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to use chart-js and react-chartjs-2 but is showing following error:

Failed to compile.

```
./node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist/index.modern.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'chart.js/auto' in 'C:\Users\An\chart-react\project-folder\client\node_modules\react-chartjs-2\dist'
```

my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

function ChartData() {
  const data = {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "# of Votes",
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
      },
    ],
  };

  const options = {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Bar data={data} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ChartData;
```

installed dependencies:

"chart.js": "^2.9.4",
"react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.3"

Answer (score 6):

Installing the latest version of `chart.js` should fix this.

```
# with npm
npm install chart.js@latest

# with yarn
yarn add chart.js@latest
```

This will update `chart.js` to latest version (currently `3.3.0`).

I believe it will work as long as the `chart.js` major version is `3+`.

---

Here is a working [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-bassi-xbmvm?file=/package.json:204-209) with the latest version of `chart.js` installed.

---

*More notes*

You are using v2 of `chart.js` but v3 of `react-chartjs-2`.

The `react-chartjs-2` [peer dependencies](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/blob/master/package.json#L44) specify using `chart.js` version `^3.1.0`. They also mention using v3 of `chart.js` in the [README](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2#we-recommend-using-chartjs-300).

The `npm` or `yarn` install commands above should be enough if you are ok with using the latest version of `chart.js`.